# Series of logarithmic function - How to determine if it converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I determine that this series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1 + \frac {x}{n^3})$
converges pointwise for $-1 < x < 1$?

I was hoping to maybe be able to prove it with the comparison test, but I am not able to rewrite it into something easier to handle.

Comment: Try limit comparison test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$, it converges.

if $x\ne 0$, we use the equivalence

$$\ln (1+a)\sim a \;\; (a\to 0) $$

which gives

$$\ln (1+\frac{x}{n^3})\sim \frac {x}{n^3} \;\;(n\to +\infty ) $$

and since $\sum \frac {1}{n^3} $ converges, we conclude that
$\sum \frac {x}{n^3} $ and  $\sum \ln (1+\frac {x}{n^3}) $ converge.